# Group By name by showing only the first records

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-schema

can anyone tell me how can I use group by to only 3 columns?
here is my table(sample1)

```
|vendorid | storeid | yearid | earnamount  |Name |
|---------|---------|--------|-------------|-----|
|1        |   2     | 2007   | 100         |  A  |   
|1        |   2     | 2007   | 150         |  C  |  
|1        |   3     | 2007   | 100         |  E  |  
|2        |   2     | 2008   | 500         |  F  |  
|2        |   2     | 2007   | 200         |  H  |  
|2        |   2     | 2008   | 500         |  J  |  
|3        |   1     | 2007   | 100         |  L  |  
|4        |  4      | 2008   | 230         |  N  |
```

I want my result to be like this:
showing the result with the Name column showing only the first in the record

```
|vendorid | storeid | yearid | sum(earnamount) | Name |
|---------|---------|--------|-----------------|------|
|1        |  2      | 2007   |    250          | A    |
|1        |  3      | 2007   |    100          | E    |
|2        |  2      | 2008   |    1000         | F    |
|2        |  2      | 2007   |    200          | H    |
|3        |   1     | 2007   |    100          | L    |
|4        |   4     | 2008   |    230          | N    |
```

here is my sql command:

```
select vendorid, storeid, yearid, sum(earnamount), name
from sample1
group by vendorid,storeid, yearid
```

not sure what is the next step on this.

Comment: select vendorid, storeid, yearid, sum(earnamount), MAX(name)AS NAME
from sample1
group by vendorid,storeid, yearid

Comment: what database are you using? solution options can differ for some databases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no "first" record, unless a column defines the ordering.  To do what you want, you need an aggregation function on `name`.  For instance:

```
select vendorid, storeid, yearid, sum(earnamount),
       min(name) as name
from sample1
group by vendorid, storeid, yearid;
```

If you want the name associated with the smallest or largest `earnamount` (for instance), you can use conditional aggregation:

```
select vendorid, storeid, yearid, sum(earnamount),
       first_name
from (select s1.*,
             first_value(name) over (partition by vendorid, storeid, yearid order by earnamount desc) as first_name
      from sample1 s1
     ) s1
group by vendorid, storeid, yearid, first_name;
```

Answer (score 0):

If a select block does have a GROUP BY clause, any column specification specified in the SELECT clause must exclusively occur as a parameter of an aggregated function or in the list of columns given in the GROUP BY clause, or in both.
So remove name or add name column in the GROUP BY

```
select vendorid, storeid, yearid, sum(earnamount)
from sample1
group by vendorid,storeid, yearid
```

Or

```
select vendorid, storeid, yearid, sum(earnamount), name
from sample1
group by vendorid,storeid, yearid,name
```

Comment: I will  need the name to display only the first in the table when I group it, disregarding it's value.